# .net framework compatibility questions

Tags: c#, .net

I am newbie to the .NET Framework. I have some a question about .NET program execution.

If I am developing a .NET application using .NET Framework version 4.0, can that application be run on .NET framework 3.5 ? Are there any compatibility issues are there?

For example If I develop a dll using .NET framework 4.0, can it be referenced by another programme which is using .NET framework 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot reference a DLL compiled in .NET 4.0 from a program compiled in .NET 3.5.  .NET Framework applications are usually backward compatible -- that is, you can reference a .NET 3.5 assembly from .NET 4.0 code, but the reverse is not true.

You could try compiling the .NET 3.5 project in 4.0, or compiling the .NET 4.0 assembly in .NET 3.5, either of which will work if they are an option.

Answer (score 3):

.Net Framework is generally backward compatible, so you can load a .Net 3.5 assembly in a .Net 4 runtime, but not vice-versa.

You should target your assemblies at the lowest supported version of the runtime.

Here is some additional reading that should answer most of your questions...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx